# c++ derived class from two same base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, duplicates, virtual

Here are my classes:

```
class Base1
{
public:
    Base1();
    ~Base1();

    virtual void main_func()=0;
}

class D1 : public Base1
{
public:
    D1();
    ~D1();

    virtual void main_func(do_d1_main(););
}
class D2 : public Base1
{
public:
    D2();
    ~D2();

    virtual void main_func(){do_d2_main();};
}

class Base2
{
public:
    Base2();
    ~Base2();

    int   m_needed_by_b1;
}
class D12B2: public Base2, public D1, public D2
{
public:
    D12B2();
    ~D12B2();
}
```

Here's the problem:

Both `do_main_func1()` and `do_main_func2()` need access to member `m_needed_by_b1` in `Base2`. How?

Could I define the virtual function `main_func` for each within `class D12B2`? That would give them access to all of `D12B2`, including `Base2`. How would I specify each separately?

I thought about adding a (protected) member in `Base1`, that is a pointer to a `Base2` object. That would have to be set by `D12B2`. It seems like there might be a more elegant way to do this.

TIA

ken

Comment: One way to do this (that some people don't like) is to use multiple inheritance; make `D1` and `D2` each derive from *both* `Base1` and `Base2`.

Comment: Between `do_d1_main`, `do_d2_main`, `do_main_func1`, and `do_main_func2`, you've specified in either code or description four things, none of which have any definition. Are `do_d1_main` and `do_main_func1`(and their counterparts for `d2`) supposed to be the same function ?

Comment: This is usually considered a [design/code smell](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CodeSmell)

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @WhozCraig: `main_func` gets called by an object that only knows that this is a Base1 class. I used the `do_main_funcX()` to indicate that each DX::main_func does a different thing. @Brian Bi: that would give me two separate Base2 objects, which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like there might be a more elegant way to do this.

More than likely, there is - don't use multiple inheritance.

However, if you are going to insist on using multiple inheritance, there are some things you must note:  `D1` and `D2` should be inherited virtually in `D12B2` to avoid the diamond problem.  Assuming `do_d1_main` and `do_d2_main` actually means `main_func`, then you can implement a `D12B2::main_func` that will be able to access `m_needed_by_b1`.

But back to the original note:

It sounds like `Base1` and `Base2` should not exist, and `D1` and `D2` should be pure abstract classes.  Which would leave you with

```
class D1
{
public:
    virtual void d1_func() = 0;
};

class D2
{
public:
    virtual void d2_func() = 0;
};

class D12B2 : public virtual D1, public virtual D2
{
public:
    D12B2();
    ~D12B2();

    virtual void d1_func()
    {
        // do something
    }

    virtual void d2_func()
    {
        // do something else
    }

private:
    int m_myData;
};
```

Comment: "... to avoid the diamond problem." Did you mean "to *enforce* the diamond pattern"? Without virtual inheritance there is no diamond, which is likely a problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig I meant it will avoid the ambiguous function declaration problem - which is the [diamond problem](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html) I was referring to.

Comment: Yes, D1 and D2 should be virtualy inherited, to avoid the diamond. Sorry I left that out. But, both base classes are needed (at least I think so). Example: base1 is a thread class that creates and runs `thread_main()` in a separate thread. I define two different thread classes: audio and video (these are D1 and D2). Base2 is a generic device class that has functions needed by both the audio and video threads. D12B2 is a specific device that has both an audio thread and a video thread.

Comment: @user3182551 With that, this question becomes an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You are trying to treat a thread as a polymorphic entity when you do not need to (and likely shouldn't).

Comment: Okay, I guess I am trying the XY thing. So why should I not need the polymorphic entity (or what is it?). If you mean that `main_func` need not be virtual, it does, because the mechanism to run the thread calls that function, but it only knows about the Base1 class, and not any of the derived classes.

Comment: @user3182551 You are thinking about it in terms of a pure OOD mindset.  If you are using `std::thread` for these objects, you can do almost all of it without a single class (just a standalone function).  But your problem isn't really handling multiple inheritance, but rather how you should lay out your design for a set of video/audio playback threads.

Comment: Okay, I am thinking OOD. I am converting old C code (that has some bugs) into C++ (OOD) because the problem does lend itself well to that. I have several devices, each has low level access through the same driver code (via Base2). Any device can have audio and/or video. While the audio and video processing is different, the basic thread functionality is the same. Yes this discussion is about the design. But what about the original question? Can that be done?

Comment: @user3182551 That is the problem with XY problems - what you are asking about is not really what you need help with.  That is, your original question is meaningless if you ask the question that relates to the problem you actually need solved - because the answers to that question would never lead you to this "solution".  From what you've said, you should have a device that either plays sound, plays video, or both.  The device is not the thread - it may create the thread, but it is not, itself, a thread.  Without more details, it is hard to give specifics, though.

Comment: Okay, more generally: I want a Base2 object, that creates D1 and/or D2 objects. But D1 and D2 need access to Base2 data and functions.

Comment: re-edit: Okay, the basic original question: I want a Base2 object, that creates (or inherits)  D1 and/or D2 objects. But the virtual functions defined in D1 and D2 need access to Base2 data and functions. A derived class (D12B2) would give the D1 and D2 objects that access, but (here's the question), how do I define the separate virtual `main_func` functions from the D1 and D23 objects. For a D1B2, or D2B2 object, I know how to do that. And, just in case, I can't have both D1B2 and D2B2 objects concurrently - that would give two separate B2 objects. (Would go to chat, but I am still a newbie.)